PHP Unable To Write To Cache Directory
I'm getting the below error on a CentOS 9 Stream server when a request comes in from PHP. It looks like the phpFastCache module can't write to the cache directory.
2024/06/19 10:06:34 [error] 4789#4789: *285 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Phpfastcache\Exceptions\PhpfastcacheIOException: The directory /var/www/html/core/cache/127.0.0.1/Files could not be created.
Additional information provided by error_get_last():
mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/core/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/Core/Pool/IO/IOHelperTrait.php line 176 in /var/www/html/core/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/Core/Pool/IO/IOHelperTrait.php:177
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/core/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/Core/Pool/IO/IOHelperTrait.php(131): Phpfastcache\Drivers\Files\Driver->mkdir()
#1 /var/www/html/core/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/Drivers/Files/Driver.php(48): Phpfastcache\Drivers\Files\Driver->getPath()
#2 /var/www/html/core/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/Core/Pool/DriverBaseTrait.php(79): Phpfastcache\Drivers\Files\Driver->driverCheck()
#3 /var/www/html/core/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/C" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"

Directory permissions are:
[root@127.0.0.1 cache]# ls -laF
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  2 nginx nginx 4096 Jun 19 00:23 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 11 nginx nginx 4096 Jun 18 23:55 ../

Server is setup with:

Nginx 1.20.1
PHP 8.3.8
phpfastcache 9.2.*
Using PHP-FPM
Everything running under nginx
user


I'm not sure, but do you really think that installing PHP to the public /var/www/html directory is the right thing to do? Should the cache really be visible to public users? Maybe PHP tries to write using group rights, so your target directory needs also a chmod g+w. I also see that your server is using SELinux for those directories, cause of the last dot . at drwxr-xr-x.. You should check that too.

@paladin I've moved the cache directory out of the public web directory, will look at SELinux now, thanks.

The cause of the issue was SELinux, by running the below command it solved the issue.
setsebool -P httpd_unified=1
You can set more specific rules which is recommend but for my issue, the above solution works.
